# Partial perimeter in ArcGIS

Tags: shapefile, multi-polygon

I have a set of polygons, in turn formed by several polygons. Let's suppose a large polygon formed by three smaller polygons.

Is there any method to know the outer perimeter of the set of three polygons, and the proportion of that outer perimeter that corresponds to each of the subpolygons?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro, ArcMap or something else from the ArcGIS platform?

Comment: Thank you very much for your cooperation. I would like to clarify my problem. I work with arcmap and the question is that I have many polygons together (can be two, three, four...) and I need to know the outer perimeter of the set of polygons and to know what percentage corresponds to each of the subpolygons.

Answer (score 3):

You can `dissolve` the 3 polygons, which will give you the overall length. Then for each polygon calculate the `intersection` between it and the big polygon to get it's contribution to the perimeter.